# Using `$q.defer()` within angular's provider

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to inject $q into provider, in my case, angular throws exception telling that there is no such provider.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For a provider, the values are injected in the $get function.

```
myApp.provider('testProvider', function() {
   this.$get = function($q) {

   };
});
```

More details here:

1. [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provide-vs-factory)
2. https://gist.github.com/Mithrandir0x/3639232

Comment: Is it possible to declare the $get function using minification-safe way? (i.e. `['$q', function($q){ ... }]`)

Comment: @Lu4 I assume you've already found your answer, but for the Googlers here; yes, this is possible. `$get: ['$q', function ($q) {})]`

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen this was exactly what I was looking for and is likely the 'correct' way to do it.